# Assert that Collection contains 2 Objects with same property using matchers

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4, hamcrest

I have the following scenario, where I want to test someFunction():

```
Collection<MyObject> objects = someFunction(someInput);
assertThat(objects , contains(hasProperty("property", is(propertyIWantToTest))));
```

This works fine if `Collection<MyObject> objects` should have just 1 `MyObject object` according to `someInput` which is passed to `someFunction()`.
However, there are some cases for `someInput` that the `Collection<MyObject> objects` should have 2 or more `MyObject object` containg the same `propertyIWantToTest` object.
Is there a way to use Hamcrest matchers to test that?

Here's something closer to what I'm willing to achieve:

```
assertThat(objects , contains(exactlyTwoTimes(hasProperty("property", is(propertyIWantToTest)))));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to verify that every item has that property, and that there are exactly two items, then use [`everyItem`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#everyItem%28org.hamcrest.Matcher%29) and [`hasSize`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasSize%28org.hamcrest.Matcher%29):

```
assertThat(objects, everyItem(hasProperty("property", is(propertyIWantToTest))));
assertThat(objects, hasSize(2));
```

If you want to specifically test the contents of the collection, but it just so happens that both expected items are the same, use a variable and [`containsInAnyOrder`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder%28org.hamcrest.Matcher...%29):

```
Matcher<MyObject> m = hasProperty("property", is(propertyIWantToTest));
assertThat(objects, containsInAnyOrder(m, m));
```